# Text Mining - removing contents if they are in another cell

Tags: r, nlp

I have a large dataset that contains text in cells. Some of the text is just an appended cell from before and I don't want to include this in my analysis unless the date is different. This is an example of what it looks like:

1. 10-01-17 | Hi, how are you?
2. 10-01-17 | Hi, how are you? Oh, I'm just fine.
3. 11-01-17 | Hi, how are you? Oh, I'm just fine. The weather is nice today.

If 1 is in 2, I want to remove 1 if the date is the same. If 2 is in 3, remove two only if the date is the same. The only contents I want to keep are two and  three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `grepl` on the entire column, using each observation as a pattern. If the sum of the resulting Boolean vector is more than 1, that row matched more than itself and is a duplicate.

```
df[mapply(function(d, t) {
    sum(grepl(t, df$text, fixed = TRUE) & d == df$date) == 1
}, df$date, df$text), ]

##       date                                                            text
## 2 10-01-17                             Hi, how are you? Oh, I'm just fine.
## 3 11-01-17  Hi, how are you? Oh, I'm just fine. The weather is nice today.
```

or in dplyr,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>% filter(sum(grepl(text, .$text, fixed = TRUE) & date == .$date) == 1)

## Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
## Groups: <by row>
## 
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##       date                                                            text
##      <chr>                                                           <chr>
## 1 10-01-17                             Hi, how are you? Oh, I'm just fine.
## 2 11-01-17  Hi, how are you? Oh, I'm just fine. The weather is nice today.
```

---

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("10-01-17", "10-01-17", "11-01-17"
    ), text = c("Hi, how are you?", "Hi, how are you? Oh, I'm just fine.", 
    "Hi, how are you? Oh, I'm just fine. The weather is nice today."
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("date", "text"))
```

Comment: This works perfect! Appreciate it. How would you tweak it to only show 1 and three. So if the first text is in the second, only put the first text?

Comment: Maybe `df %>% group_by(date) %>% filter(rowSums(as.matrix(sapply(text, function(t){grepl(t, text, fixed = TRUE)}))) == 1)`, though there may be a more elegant way.